# Multiple hashes in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi I have a hash which I'm trying to complete but cannot quite get the last part.

I can view the collection in my console because I'm using byebug

Ruby code:

```
@data = Hash.new
    d = Date.today
    @data[:week_1] = Hash.new
    @data[:week_1][:date] = d.at_beginning_of_week.strftime("%d") + "/" + d.at_end_of_week.strftime("%d") + " " + Date::MONTHNAMES[Date.today.month] + " " + Date.today.year.to_s
    @data[:week_2] = Hash.new
    @data[:week_2][:date] = d.at_beginning_of_week.strftime("%d") + "/" + d.at_end_of_week.strftime("%d") + " " + Date::MONTHNAMES[Date.today.month] + " " + Date.today.year.to_s
    @data[:week_3] = Hash.new
    @data[:week_3][:date] = d.at_beginning_of_week.strftime("%d") + "/" + d.at_end_of_week.strftime("%d") + " " + Date::MONTHNAMES[Date.today.month] + " " + Date.today.year.to_s
    byebug
        count = 30
    money = 420.00
    @data[:weeks_1][:business_sign_ups] = {count: count, money: money}
    @data[:weeks_2][:business_sign_ups] = {count: count, money: money}
    @data[:weeks_3][:business_sign_ups] = {count: count, money: money}
```

Output in my console during debugging:

```
(byebug) @data
{:week_1=>{:date=>"23/29 July 2018"}, :week_2=>{:date=>"23/29 July 2018"}, :week_3=>{:date=>"23/29 July 2018"}}
```

I want to add `[:business_sign_ups]` to this hash for each week where their count and money values will all equal 30 and 420.00 as stated above.

Everytime I hit continue for in the byebug console I get a nil class error for []` which is the [:business_sign_ups]

Any help would be great thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo, you're trying to access `:weeks_1`, `:weeks_2`, and `:weeks_3` when you should be accessing `:week_1`, `:week_2`, and `:week_3`.

When you try to access a key in a hash that doesn't exist, it returns the hash default, which, when you initialize a hash with `Hash#new`, is `nil`. So trying to set an attribute of `@data[:weeks_1]` is like trying to use `nil` as a hash.

Comment: Oh my f***ing god. THANK YOU .